# Shiny App doesn't run properly when Fitting Mixed Models is added

Tags: r, shiny, mixed-models

I am trying to write a Shiny application using linear mixed models. On the application I want to compute the residuals of the MM to be used for later plots based on inputs from the user. Something like this:

```
datos0=reactive({
    trait=input$trait
    a=droplevels(subset(a.0, (YEAR %in% input$year)&(SEAS %in% input$season)&(LOC %in% input$location)))
    # fit a mixed linear model with COL & ROW as fixed
    # GENO as random
    MModel=as.formula(paste(trait, "~ROW+COL"))
    modelo=lme(MModel, random=~1|GENO,data=a, na.action="na.omit")
    a$res[which(!is.na(a[,trait]))]=residuals(modelo)
    a[order(a$COL, a$ROW),]
     })
```

When running this from outside Shiny I get no problem.

I can provide the complete code, but everything works OK unless I add the fitting of the mixed model (`library(nlme)` is being called on the `global.r`)

What could be wrong?

Comment: What platform does Shiny App run on?  Please describe the specific problem(s) you are seeing and documentation thereof (i.e., error log).

Comment: I am running Shiny on Windows 7, and the error message is 
Error in matrix(unlist(value), nrow = nrow(data), dimnames = list(row.names(data),  : 
  negative extents to matrix

Comment: There's a discussion of this issue on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/koRxCAU4fLc